# mod rewrite split and replace

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I need an internal redirect, where **category-slug** is a dynamic value,
that schould be appended after the **~**

```
/category/**category-slug**  /blog/?ucterms=category~**category-slug**
```

Is that possible with mod rewrite?
I have seen solutions like ?name=$1  name/$1.
But how can isolate the value right from the last slash and put it after the tilde?
Otherwise I would have to write a single line for every category.

Comment: "I have seen solutions like ?name=$1 name/$1" - That kinda sounds the same as what you are trying to do here?! Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only matching the first level after category:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category/([^/]+) /blog/?ucterms=category~$1
```

If you want to grab everything after /category/ till the end of the URL (this will include multiple levels and forward slashes etc):

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category/(.+) /blog/?ucterms=category~$1
```

I have used + for as the Quantifier so that it will redirect if there is something after ie /category/ by itself will not redirect.

Also please use the code you want such as 301, 302 etc as an example.

Using RedirectMatch will immediately redirect and stop any further processing of the .htaccess if you are using that. So you can add it where appropriate in the file.

Adding example with **RewriteRule**, you can modify each side as needed. Also as this is a simple redirect you can exclude using **RewriteCond**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ /blog/?ucterms=category~$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note the L here would mean do not process any other rules after this rule. So it is similar to the first option provided.

Think of it this way if you had 10 rules for various operations, do you want to keep processing those rules before redirecting if there is a match or just redirect early and skip all that stuff. Either way one or the other is going to run for every request to the server.

Comment: THX. That works perfect.
Is there a way to achieve the same with a RewriteRule?
So that I do not have to care about, where to add it in the file.

Comment: @joeking, I have updated the answer with your request. But personally I would  go with RedirectMatch as this is a simple requirement.

Comment:   I'll stick to your advise

Comment: Although the OP has specifically asked for an "internal redirect", not an _external_ HTTP/3xx redirect? (A change in URL like this would usually make more sense to be an internal rewrite, although the question does not actually state the file that should handle the request. One might assume it is `/blog/index.php`?) @joeking

Comment: @MrWhite, that is a very interesting observation. You are an expert in this area and make a valid point. My assumption for file was based on the use of 'mod rewrite' in the title and content of the question. Also the order of the two URL's in the question and mention of having to write multiple lines  to achieve this pointed at something intended for .htaccess and the use of 'internal redirect' just part of formulating the question. Looks like the answer was accepted, but I am definitely curious if there was more to this and I can update if so.